# Jointlcmm error when trying to use competing risks

Tags: r, survival, latent-class

I am still attempting to use jointLCMM to model trajectories of  a risk variable while controlling for data missing not at random due to survival events.

I am trying to control for multiple events resulting in sequence truncation. My code for the survival component is

```
Surv(time_event, status)~covariate, hazard="Weibull"
```

I keep getting an error message

> Error in rep(c(sqrt(sum(devt == i)/sum(tsurv[devt == i])), 1), ifelse(risqcom ==  : 
>     invalid 'times' argument

When I was running it without competing events, using

```
Surv(entrytime, exittime, event_flag)
```

it worked fine. I tried a bunch of potential fixes but none of them worked. Have any of you got ideas of what this error message means/how to fix it? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone in the future has this problem- the issue ended up being that I had four competing risk events (censoring, outcome A, outcome B, outcome C). After I collapsed outcomes B and C the model was able to run.